# Unable to use root_validator and validator decorator in same Pydantic class

Tags: python, pydantic

I have defined a Pydantic class as shown below -

```
class RequestOTP(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: str
```

To validate field `email` Pydantic has a class `EmailStr` and upon testing it is working just fine.

Result -

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "email"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid email address",
      "type": "value_error.email"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to add validation to the `password` field as well. So I wrote a simple regex which would validated the password. To incorporate this validation I updated the same `RequestOTP` class as shown below -

```
def validate_password(password: str) -> str:
    pattern = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%#*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!#%*?&]{8,12}$"
    is_valid = bool(re.match(pattern, password))

    if not is_valid:
        raise ValueError(
            "Your password isn't strong enough"
        )

    return password


class RequestOTP(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: str

    _validate_password = validator("password")(validate_password)
```

This is also working just as expected.

Result -

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "email"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid email address",
      "type": "value_error.email"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "Your password isn't strong enough",
      "type": "value_error"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to make some database queries where I want to verify if the provided email exist in the db and if it exist then whether the provided password for the email is same as the password in the database.

Hence, to accomplish this I will need both the email and the password in the same validate method. So I decided to use the decorator `@root_validator`.

```
def validate_password(password: str) -> str:
    pattern = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%#*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!#%*?&]{8,12}$"
    is_valid = bool(re.match(pattern, password))

    if not is_valid:
        raise ValueError(
            "Your password isn't strong enough"
        )

    return password


class RequestOTP(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: str

    _validate_password = validator("password")(validate_password)

    @root_validator
    def validate(cls, values) -> str:
        email = values.get('email')
        password = values.get('password')
        print(email, password)
        # Todo: See if email exist in the table.
        # Todo: See if is_active flag is set to True.
        # Todo: See if the password is correct for the given email.
        return values
```

Now when I provide the incorrect email & password to this class it does not raises an error. It simply accepts it.

How can I use `@validator` and `@root_validator` in the same pydantic class?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Trying to initialize `RequestOTP(email="foo", password="bar")` results in the expected validation error: `2 validation errors for RequestOTP \\ email \\ value is not a valid email address (type=value_error.email) \\ password \\ Your password isn't strong enough (type=value_error)` So no issues here. Also, just so you know, you can use previously validated field values in a regular `validator` via the `values` parameter: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Comment: The library author does not recommend doing [IO operations in validators](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2333#:~:text=I%20would%20avoid%20doing%20any%20IO%20(e.g.%20database%20access%20in%20validators)): "I would avoid doing any IO (e.g. database access in validators)". That is probably a responsibility better suited for someone else, not a pydantic model.